# How to find an element containing comment and replace it?

Tags: jquery

I have some content being outputted from a wysiwyg editor. The editor frustratingly adds `<p>` tags round every new block of content and returns something like this:

```
    <div class="content">
      <p>lots of content in here.</p> 
      <p><!--pagebreak--></p>
      <p>lots more content in here.</p> 
      <p><!--pagebreak--></p>
      <p>more content here...</p>
   </div>
```

I need to replace all instances of `<p><!--pagebreak--></p>` with `<br><br>` to allow another function to run correctly but am strugglng to work out how I'd do that?

Ive read through a number of posts which has been useful but they all seem to reference ether an element with an id/unique class associated or text rather than a comment. My best guess so far would be something along the lines of `$("<p><!—pagebreak—></p>").replaceWith("<br><br>");` which clearly doesn't work.

Can anyone offer any help?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Looking at anothe post this seems to be quite close:

```
var str = "<p><!--pagebreak--></p>";
  var newhtml = $('.container').html().replace(str, '<br><br>');
  $('.content').html(newhtml);
```

However this only removes teh first instance of `<p><!--pagebreak--></p>`

Comment: It is better practice to target an element and not target comments. You could do `<p><PageBreak /></p>`. Now you wouldn't need JavaScript, you could target this with CSS. If you have control over this section of the HTML, I would recommend against using comments for this purpose.

Comment: I know it'd not the best way to do things but I have little control over the ouputted content as the wysiwyg editor strips out all but the most basic html code. That being said it would probably be possible for the end user to type ##break meaning the resulting output would be `<p>##break</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You could find the div, find the nested p elements, filter on those that contain the comment, and replace them.

```js
$('.content').find('p').filter(function(){
  return this.innerHTML.indexOf('<!--pagebreak-->') > -1;
}).replaceWith('<br><br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>lots of content in here.</p>
  <p>
    <!--pagebreak-->
  </p>
  <p>lots more content in here.</p>
  <p>
    <!--pagebreak-->
  </p>
  <p>more content here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I also need to remove the p tags surrounding the comment.

Comment: @bigdave does this achieve what you want?

Comment: You can use jquery replacewith function to replace all found p tags.